# How to use multiple identical i2c sensors on NodeMCU V3

Tags: lua, sensors, esp8266, nodemcu

I have an ESP8266 (ESP-12) NodeMCU V3 with 2 identical sensors TSL2561.
If I want to get two values, am I doing the right thing?

```
status = tsl2561.init(4, 5, tsl2561.ADDRESS_FLOAT, tsl2561.PACKAGE_T_FN_CL)
if status == tsl2561.TSL2561_OK then
  first = tsl2561.getlux()
end

status = tsl2561.init(4, 5, tsl2561.ADDRESS_GND, tsl2561.PACKAGE_T_FN_CL)
if status == tsl2561.TSL2561_OK then
  second = tsl2561.getlux()
end
```

I haven't tried it yet, I'm waiting for sensors from Aliexpress.

Answer (score 0):

Each TSL2561 can be configured us use one of three i2c addresses. See the datasheet: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TSL2561.pdf

If you have ordered sensors on an Adafruit or a similar board then there will be an 'addr' pin that you can connect to Gnd, Vdd or leave floating to set the address for that board.  Fairly obviously, the Nodemcu software recognises these addresses as tsl2561.ADDRESS_GND, etc.

This assumes you plan to put both sensors on the same i2c bus (a, simple, sensible choice).   Alternatively you could run two separate i2c busses, in which case you don't need to change the i2c address of either sensor.

Comment: My question is about using of TSL2561 Lua module twice in one code not about soldering of addr pin. As you can see in my code above i know about GND/FLOAT/VCC options.

Answer (score 0):

As possible solution it can be rewritten using i2c module

```
local SCLPIN = 1 -- pin 1 / D1 / GPIO5
local SDAPIN = 2 -- pin 2 / D2 / GPIO4
local TSL1_ADDR = 0x29 -- soldered to GND
local TSL2_ADDR = 0x39 -- not soldered (FLOAT)
local I2C_ID = 0 -- the only bus

function writebyte(bus, device, reg, val)
    i2c.start(bus)
    i2c.address(bus, device, i2c.TRANSMITTER)
    i2c.write(bus, reg)
    i2c.write(bus, val)
    i2c.stop(bus)
end

function readbyte(bus, device, reg)
    i2c.start(bus)
    i2c.address(bus, device, i2c.TRANSMITTER)
    i2c.write(bus, reg)
    i2c.stop(bus)
    i2c.start(bus)
    i2c.address(bus, device, i2c.RECEIVER)
    b = i2c.read(bus, 1)
    i2c.stop(bus)
    return string.byte(b)
end

function loop()
    -- light1
    writebyte(I2C_ID, TSL1_ADDR, 0x80, 0x03) -- enable
    writebyte(I2C_ID, TSL1_ADDR, 0x81, 0x02) -- set timing 402ms & gain 1x
    writebyte(I2C_ID, TSL1_ADDR, 0x80, 0x00) -- disable
    tmr.delay(1000)
    writebyte(I2C_ID, TSL1_ADDR, 0x80, 0x03) -- enable
    tmr.delay(500000)
    c = readbyte(I2C_ID, TSL1_ADDR, 0x8C) -- read 0 channel (fullspectrum low)
    d = readbyte(I2C_ID, TSL1_ADDR, 0x8D) -- read 0 channel (fullspectrum high)
    l1=c+d*256
    
    -- light2
    writebyte(I2C_ID, TSL2_ADDR, 0x80, 0x03) -- enable
    writebyte(I2C_ID, TSL2_ADDR, 0x81, 0x02) -- set timing 402ms & gain 1x
    writebyte(I2C_ID, TSL2_ADDR, 0x80, 0x00) -- disable
    tmr.delay(1000)
    writebyte(I2C_ID, TSL2_ADDR, 0x80, 0x03) -- enable
    tmr.delay(500000)
    c = readbyte(I2C_ID, TSL2_ADDR, 0x8C) -- read 0 channel (fullspectrum low)
    d = readbyte(I2C_ID, TSL2_ADDR, 0x8D) -- read 0 channel (fullspectrum high)
    l2=c+d*256

    makesomethingwith(l1,l2)
end
```